# The value of the local variable is not used

Tags: java, warnings

I have an extremly basic code that looks like this:

```
boolean[][] nodes = new boolean[sectionCountX][sectionCountZ];
        for(boolean[] n1 : nodes)
            for(boolean n2 : n1) // complain about unused variable
                n2 = true;
```

and despite the fact that I set n2 to true Eclipse gives me a Warning telling me that n2 is never used.

I know that I could use a counter loop but I'm interessted in the cause of this.

Comment: What you have there is a costly no-op. This code doesn't do anything other than consuming CPU cycles. Changing the value of n2 won't change the value of the boolean in the array. You need to use `n1[i] = true` to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to initialize your array by using an enhanced for loop, which doesn't work.

What you are doing here instead is creating a bunch of local variables and initializing them, which accomplishes nothing, hence the warning from Eclipse.

I would recommend using [`Arrays.fill()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28boolean%5B%5D,%20boolean%29) instead:

```
boolean[][] nodes = new boolean[sectionCountX][sectionCountZ];
for (boolean[] n1 : nodes) {
    Arrays.fill(n1, true);
}
```

Comment: Dang it. I mixed up reference and copy. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

The term `used` is used in the sense of evaluating. You never evaluate `n2`. For example, you don't do

```
System.out.println(n2);
```

It's giving you a hint/warning because `n2` is basically useless, so why even waste resources declaring it and assigning it?

If you are trying to set the value of each boolean in your `nodes` array to `true`, what you are doing won't work.